# Unable scrape an element that still available in 'view source code'

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to **scrape** an element which is still available in 'view source code' but i fail to achieve it.

I tried with `cURL` also but ended in vain.

```
<div class="filter">
   <ul class="view-as">
      <li class="refine only-for-small facet-panel-trigger"><a href="#" rel="nofollow"><span class="hide-for-tiny">Filters</span></a></li>
      <li class="label hide-for-tiny">View as:</li>
      <li class="option view-as-grid">
         <span class="active">
         <span class="visuallyhidden">
         Grid
         </span>
         </span>
      </li>
      <li class="option view-as-list">
         <a href="/c/home/kitchenware/cookware/W404651?N=27fj&Nrpp=30&viewAs=list" rel="nofollow">
         <span class="visuallyhidden">List</span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="pager-refine divided">
      <ul class="pager pager-pages">
         <li class="previous option">
         </li>
         <li class="label hide-for-small">
            <strong>Page 1</strong> of 2
         </li>
         <li class="next option">
            <a href="/c/home/kitchenware/cookware/W404651?N=27fj&Nrpp=30&viewAs=grid&page=1" title="Next Page">
            <span class="iconf iconf-right-arrow-large" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe601;"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get `<div class="pager-refine divided">` but it returns empty.

I found the above code in **View Source Code** of Chrome Browser

**#UPDATE 1**

When I try the following code

```
echo $pagnationContent = $childPage->find("div.filter",0);
```

it displays only

```
    <div class="filter">
           <ul class="view-as">
              <li class="refine only-for-small facet-panel-trigger"><a href="#" rel="nofollow"><span class="hide-for-tiny">Filters</span></a></li>
              <li class="label hide-for-tiny">View as:</li>
              <li class="option view-as-grid">
                 <span class="active">
                 <span class="visuallyhidden">
                 Grid
                 </span>
                 </span>
              </li>
              <li class="option view-as-list">
                 <a href="/c/home/kitchenware/cookware/W404651?N=27fj&Nrpp=30&viewAs=list" rel="nofollow">
                 <span class="visuallyhidden">List</span>
                 </a>
              </li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

**#UPDATE 2**

```
function readThisPage($url){


ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0 FirePHP/0.5 ');

$context = stream_context_create (array ('http' => array ('timeout' => 60)));
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


return $buffer;


}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code that is failing as well as the data you are trying to scrape.

Comment: you want html content under this <div class="pager-refine divided">

Comment: Please post the curl code that u r requesting the page, and also pls try to disable the javascript on the browser, open the page again, and view the source again, if the data you need is not inside the element it means it is being inserted by js after page load, curl does not support js, so you should take that info from somewhere else.

Comment: @dav I have checked with javascript disabled. its still available there in view source code. Also I have updated the question

Comment: Maybe consider posting the page link for us to check (Then you can remove it later) in order to help you better...

Comment: It works for me. Echo the response, make sure it's really there.